# @Formula with "order by" (lowercase) throws java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using "order by" with lower case at @Formula query string throws **java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**

```
    public class User {
       @Formula("(SELECT string_agg(_a._teamname,';') FROM (SELECT t.name as _teamname FROM team t, teammember tm WHERE tm.team=t.id AND tm.user=id order by t.name) AS _a)")
       proctected String teamNames;
    }
```

**Hibernate-core-5.4.20**

Comment: Wouldn't this be more useful if sent to Hibernate's development team?

Comment: I jus register to Hibernate Jira an post the issue, thanks. https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14427

Answer (score 1):

When hibernate compute the subselectQueryFragment the index detected is not valid:
**formIndex > orderByIndex**.
A workaround can be use **ORDER BY** (with UPPER CASE at @Formula) and extend it as good practice to all sql Formula keywords: FROM, WHERE,...

**Hibernate-core-5.4.20**

```
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.SubselectFetch.createSubselectFetchQueryFragment(QueryParameters)

    final int fromIndex = getFromIndex( queryString );
    final int orderByIndex = queryString.lastIndexOf( "order by" );
    final String subselectQueryFragment =  orderByIndex > 0
                ? queryString.substring( fromIndex, orderByIndex )   // -> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException 
                : queryString.substring( fromIndex );
```

**Hibernate builds queryString**

```
   select 
     (...)
     (SELECT string_agg(_a._teamname,';') FROM (SELECT t.name as _teamname FROM team t, teammember tm WHERE tm.team=t.id AND tm.user=:id order by t.name) AS _a) as formula2_2_
     from 
       teammember teammember0_ 
     where (... without order by)
```